# Which is the right container to manage small objects which map to some other small objects?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I have a set of small objects. Each of these objects points to other objects. These pointers might be realized as actual pointers or as index into an array of the objects or something else. It might be an array of such pointers whose length might change. There might be pointers to objects of the same type and to other types, but this is known at compile time.

So, for example: I have a class Person. This person has two pointers to its parent Persons. There's another class Place. Each Person has a list of pointers to all Places he/she has visited.

In contrast to an actual family tree, I might want to change the tree from time to time by deleting/inserting some Persons.

Is there a container in the C++ Standard Library (C++ 11) for that purpose or should I better look for a dedicated memory management class?

I will have to pass the data to a C interface why I would prefer a storage method which is based on an accessible (read only) linear array.

Comment: As long as the final paragraph applies, `std::vector` is pretty much your only choice. Note that there is a bunch of algorithms in the STL for dealing with sorted vectors, which might come in handy here.

Comment: Does that sound like a use for Flyweight?

Comment: Are you actually asking about the STL or did you want to know about the containers in the C++ Standard Library? (I'll give you a hint: you're almost definitely asking about the C++ Standard Library, not the ancient non-standard library called the STL upon which it was partially based).

Comment: I'm asking about the containers in `std::`. From my ancient first C++ book, I know this as the STL. And as far as I see, many other people also use this term. I have no idea "how wrong" it is to use the word STL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Questions:

1. "There might be pointers to objects of the same type and to other types, but this is known at compile time."
2. "These pointers might be realized as actual pointers or as index into an array of the objects or something else."
3. In contrast to an actual family tree, I might want to change the tree from time to time by deleting/inserting some Persons.
4. "Is there a container in the C++ Standard Library (C++ 11) for that purpose or should I better look for a dedicated memory management class?"
5. "I will have to pass the data to a C interface why I would prefer a storage method which is based on an accessible (read only) linear array."

## Answers:

1. This could become difficult if you want to use pointers to multiple types of objects in a single container. But you could make either a raw array or a `std::vector` work.
2. If you're just using indices that would greatly simplify your "pointers to multiple types" problem. Again either a raw array or a `std::vector` work.
3. Dynamically changing raw array sizes gets sketchy fast, I'd say this is a point for `std::vector`.
4. Depending upon the time that you are willing to put in, managing your memory is a tremendous endeavor, I'd stick with a raw array or `std::vector` until they pried my cold dead fingers loose.
5. If you have C++11 using `std::vector::data` can make a `std::vector` just as usable as a raw array here, if not this would be simpler to implement as a raw array.

`std::vector` has numerous benefits to you as the programmer. Not the least of which is automatic memory management. So I'd lean toward `std::vector` where it is an option.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a great time to quote [Stepanov](http://www.slashslash.info/tag/stepanov/):

> Use vectors whenever you can. If you cannot use vectors, redesign your solution so that you can use vectors.

The "accessible linear array" part points to `vector<Person>` - none of the other containers have that feature - and the rest of your use-case doesn't suggest any specific kind storage or access. Part of it sounds like it might be cleaner if you could do `vector<shared_ptr<Person>>` but that would break your C interface requirement.  So `vector<Person>` is probably your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use vector rather than other (list, etc) . as Bjarne said "If you know int and vector, so you know C++". 
Here is the link at Youtube, as Bjarne said about vector:
[Bjarne Stroustrup: Why you should avoid Linked Lists](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQs6IC-vgmo)

Comment: I don't think he was trying to say you should never use linked lists, just not to search them - but good link, thank you.

Comment: :D yes, he just explained about disadvantages of list